# Is it possible to trigger an Alexa skill every time a specific voice profile speaks

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to make it such that every time I speak with my Alexa, it passes what I say to this one specific skill, but not for everyone else.

I can't figure out if there's a way to trigger a skill beyond saying the invocation phrase, but I want the skill to be invoked every time I (with my voice profile) say something, regardless of what it is

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported. Interactions with a skill must begin with a user verbally or physically interacting with the device in question.

That said, as a developer you can submit feature requests and ideas in our uservoice space via the following link:
https://alexa.uservoice.com/